# Count the unique values ​in mongodb and the parameters associated with them

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

the collections in my database are structured as follows

```
{ _id: , itemNumber: 123452, value: 15, user: 'Mark'},
{ _id: , itemNumber: 123452, value: 12, user: 'Tom'},
{ _id: , itemNumber: 123452, value: 1, user: 'Mark'},
{ _id: , itemNumber: 123452, value: 23, user: 'Tom'},
{ _id: , itemNumber: 123452, value: 13, user: 'Daniel'},
{ _id: , itemNumber: 123452, value: 56, user: 'Mark'},
{ _id: , itemNumber: 123452, value: 13, user: 'Mark'},
```

I would like to query the database in such a way that the values ​​are returned according to the assumption below:

```
{user: Mark, sumValue: 85, amount: 4}
{user: Daniel, sumValue: 13, amount: 1}
{user: Tom, sumValue: 35, amount: 2}
```

Finally, I would like to pass this data to the renderer to the front.
I tried queries using db.distinct but unfortunately I'm learning node.js so far, so I will be grateful for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$group` in an aggregation stage like this:

- `$group` by name to get all data from each user.
- Create field `sumValue` using `$sum` the value
- Create field `amount` with `$sum` only one to get the count.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$user",
      "sumValue": {
        "$sum": "$value"
      },
      "amount": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1d0AtKjnzwD)